# Audio in the entire system freezes if one application is paused on a breakpoint

Tags: fedora, audio, alsa, pipewire

I'm making a game using SDL2. When I'm debugging it and pause on a breakpoint, the audio in all other applications (e.g. Firefox) freezes, as if infinitely replaying the last ~0.1 seconds of audio.

When I continue debugging (leave the breakpoint), the audio becomes unstuck.

Judging from the thread names I see in the debugger (`alsa-pipewire`, `SDLHotplugALSA`), SDL2 uses Pipewire as the audio backend. I remember this working correctly in Ubuntu, perhaps because a different audio backend was used there.

I'm looking for some non-intrusive way to not affect other applications with my debugging, either by changing some Pipewire configs, or by changing the code of my own application.

Comment: In what exactly are you leaving the breakpoints? Because I'm trying to reproduce with a SDL-based application using alsa-pipewire, and I can't reproduce at all; halting all threads of ffplay using that configuration doesn't stop or interrupt other applications playing sounds. Are you perhaps setting a breakpoint in the pipewire daemon itself, accidentally?

Comment: @MarcusMüller No, my breakpoint is in the main thread. Perhaps it's because I built SDL2 myself, rather than installing from the package manager.

Comment: that wouldn't change the interface that pipewire has, so there has to be something else at play (pun not fully unintended)

Comment: (I mean, logically, one client freezing shouldn't freeze the audio system, that'd be just bad design)